# enable Stack canaries protection in android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

- We would like to know how to compile the specific c binary file(.so) in android studio using -fstack-protector flag
- How can we check whether this file is remove after compiling in android studio .
- Is there a way to enable this flag before compiling?